# How to get valus passed using putserializable using bundle from Arraylist<Hashmap<String,String>>

Tags: java, android, arraylist, hashmap, serializable

I created a list using the following, which gets the value from model class which has getter and setter.

```
    int k = model.getChildren().size();
    for(int i=0;i < k;i++) {
        HashMap<String, String> map = new HashMap<String, String>();
        galleryChildModel = model.getChildren().get(i);
        map.put("caption", galleryChildModel.getImagecaption());
        map.put("imageurl", galleryChildModel.getImageurl());
        list.add(map);
    }
```

then im passing this value to next fragment using this setOnItemClickListener

```
       gridchild.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            Fragment fragment = new GalleryDetailFragment();
            Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
            bundle.putSerializable("object", list.get(position));
            fragment.setArguments(bundle);
            FragmentManager fragmentManager = getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager();
            FragmentTransaction fragmentTransaction = fragmentManager.beginTransaction();
            fragmentTransaction.replace(R.id.container_body, fragment);
            fragmentTransaction.addToBackStack(null);
            fragmentTransaction.commit();
        }
    });
```

i'm getting the value in the respective fragment using

```
   Bundle bundle = this.getArguments();

    if (bundle != null) {
          ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> maps = (ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>>) bundle.get("object"); // here i cannot cast the value to hashmap or any list. im really stuck here can anyone help me out with this
    }
```

the value im getting is like this

Bundle[{ object=[{
imageurl=http://futhead.cursecdn.com/static/img/15/players/20801.png,caption=Ronaldo.}]}]

how to get data from this and set to a textview and imageview....

Comment: what type is `list` ?

Comment: ArrayList<HashMap<String, String>> list; //i cannot cast the value, it shows unchecked cast and gives error

Comment: Then you have to cast it to ArrayList not to HashMap

Comment: @Blackbelt i tried that but i shows unchecked cast

Comment: Unchecked cast: 'java.lang.Object' to 'java.util.ArrayList<java.util.HashMap<java.lang.String,java.lang.String>>

Comment: This is just the warning. Code should compile just fine.

Comment: but i couldn't get the value of imageurl and caption....

i get only empty screen in detailpagescreen

Comment: maps show null when i debug

java.lang.ClassCastException: java.util.HashMap cannot be cast to java.util.ArrayList

this is the error when i run

Comment: Thank you so much @mikeD....

Comment: If my answer wasa correct and helped please mark it as answer to your question. Glad I could help.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
bundle.putSerializable("object", list.get(position));
```

Your Serializable stored under "object" is a HashMap not List so you should cast to a Hashmap:

```
HashMap<String,String> map = (HashMap<String, String>) bundle.getSerializable("object");
```

Comment: there is another problem in this.... the list is keeps on repeating as i move to next activity and comeback is ther eany way to stop it

Comment: What do you mean by repeaeting. You need to clarify on that.

Comment: Thanks but i solved it by adding adapter ==null before executing list and it works